# Is the game fair or unfair?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a box there are 20 balls, 10 are red and 10 black. An automaton draw randomly successively the 20 balls.

The player wins if at any time during the drawing of 20 balls more black than red balls are drawn, else he has lost.

With a stake of \$10, the player may lose the stake (\$10) or win \$100.

Is this a fair game? (Explain your answer mathematically).

thank you

Comment: The question as stated is trivial as shown by @Ross Millikan.  I strongly suspect you have not written it up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  for the given payoff, consider what happens on the first draw.  It would be much harder if you were asked to compute the fair payoff.

Comment: if the first ball is black the player win $100 and if the ball  is red he lose

Comment: No, if the ball is red, the game continues. @Noah

Comment: @noah either your question is phrased wrong, or you are misunderstanding what you wrote. It never says the player loses if here are more red balls. You keep drawing. Otherwise, the game is absolutely sill and trivial

Comment: Your first comment is not quite right:  if the first ball is black the player wins, if it is red he might still win.  But if the player wins 100 with chance 1/2 on the first ball, he is already ahead-the expectation is 50, so the game is not fair.  This shows the payoff should be less than 20 for a fair game.

Comment: A more explicit response to Noah's second comment: If the first ball drawn is red but the next two are black, then, according to the rules you gave in the question, the player wins.  There is a time, namely after the first three balls are drawn, when more black than red balls have been drawn, namely two black and one red.

Comment: ok i have may be an idea: let B=black and R=red balls. $B_1 \dots B_{10} R_1 \dots R_10$ this can an example of a drawing. In this case the player win right? Now if i want to know if this game fair or not i must find a way to know if the player have 1/2 Chance to win. But i dont know how to do this and how to explain it mathematically ...

Comment: A fair game does not necessarily give the player $1/2$ chance to win.  It gives the player an expected dollar return of $0$.  In your game, the player wins 100 or loses 10, so it would be fair if the player won $1/11$ of the time.  We have quickly shown that the player wins somewhat more than $1/2$, so the game is in the player's favor.

Comment: To accurately compute the player's chance of winning, you need the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).  The eighth example is specifically your problem